# Полноэкранный режим редактирования в Qt Creator

Tags: qt, ide, qtcreator

Как в редакторе Qt Creator открыть файл из проекта (.cpp) для редактирования в отдельном окне? Не в раздельной панели, а именно в новом окне, которое можно было бы растянуть на весь экран?

Недавно как-то я такое сделал, было очень удобно, а сейчас не могу вспомнить, как именно это получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы открыть новое окно, просто нажмите <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>4</kbd> или меню Window->Open in new Window

Comment: А Ctrl+E,4 это как надо нажимать? Я нажал ctrl, потом по очереди E и 4 , ничего не произошло.

Comment: Разобрался, надо нажать сначала ctrl+E , затем (отпустив ctrl и E) нажать 4

Comment: конечно, нужно отпускать ctrl - там же запятая нарисована. Но она не отмечена как кнопка.